# Relationship between $ord (a)$, $ord (b)$, $ord(ab)$

Tags: group-theory

If $a,b\in G$, $G$ is an abelian group, how do I prove that $$ord(ab)\mid lcm(ord(a),ord(b))$$ where ord is "order" and lcm is "least common multiple"？
If we denote $ord(a)$, $ord(b)$, $ord(ab)$ as $m$, $n$, $q$, respectively, then $q$ is the least positive integer such that $a^{q}b^{q}=e$， i.e. $a^q=b^{-q}$.
Then there are two cases:
$$a^q=b^{-q}=e$$
or $$a^q=b^{-q}≠e.$$
In the first case it's obvious that $q=icm(m,n)$ so $q|icm(m,n)$ but in the second case I have no clue at all.

Comment: how do you arrive at $a^{\text{ord}(ab)}b^{\text{ord}(ab)}=e$? You haven't really ran through this step by step or explained your steps.

Comment: @DavidP I said it's an abelian group so it's obvious. $a^qb^q=(ab)^q=e$.

Comment: See also the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3442995/completing-the-proof-if-a-and-b-commute-then-rm-ordab-is-a-divisor?rq=1) for a more general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=lcm(ord(a),ord(b))$. Then $(ab)^k=a^kb^k=e$ since $k$ is divisible by both $ord(a)$ and $ord(b)$. It is well-known that this implies $ord(ab)\mid k$ (consider $k$ mod $ord(ab)$).

Comment: Oh god I got it. $k$ must be a multiple of $ord(ab)$ otherwise $(ab)^k$ would not be $e$. I am a little dumb lol.